# where to place the header and lib files

Tags: c++, header-files

I have program which I need for a graphic interface. In the installation it says I should copy the "some_header.h" in my favorite include directory and the "libsomething.so" in my favorite lib directory. I know copied them to /usr/include/program-name and to /usr/lib/program-name respectively. When I know try to compile a c++ program using this graphic program, I get the error 'fatal error: some_header.h: No such file or directory, #include "some_header.h"'
What do I have to do, so the file is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compile your application with:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/program-name -L/usr/lib/program-name -lsomething .......
```

and this should sort out the directories.

`-I` is for include directories

`-L` is for library directories

`-l` is to use the given library

Another solution for the header file is to put it in the directory where your source is and then `#include "some_header.h"` is supposed to work out of the box.

**Update**

Of course, you always can put your files in standard system directories, such as: `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include`

Comment: I compile using a makefile. Is there no place where it is found directly? The project I want to compile is an older one. At the time I didn't need to specify the include or lib directory. Has the way its dealt changed or was the file in a different place then?

Comment: @user2758804 I don't know where your files were then, but I update the answer :)